# Excel-VBA: High performance sheet update

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I have a working code that updates cell entries in Sheet "B" with reference to entries in Sheet "A". However, the code is slow (the tables are really huge). Can anybody show me how to do it more efficiently?

```
Sub UpdateList()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 to 1000
        For Each c in Sheets("A").Range("C8:C10000").Cells
            If c.value = i Then
                Sheets("B").Range("D" & i) = Sheets("B").Range("D" & i).value & "; " _
                & Sheets("A").Range("X" & c.Row).value
            End if
        Next c
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End
```

I am curious what I could do better. Thanks!

Comment: What you are asking for is a code review. Don't think this is the place for it. However, just as a quick point, capture your range from `SheetA` into an array. Then build a separate array for `SheetB`. Once done, you can paste your array for `ShhetB` directly into `SheetB`. It is a lot quicker to work from memory rather than from sheets in excel

Comment: Come over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with @zac. In fact I would make 3 arrays. One for `Sheet A Col C`, Second for `Sheet A Col X` and the 3rd for `Sheet B Col D`. I just tested the code that I wrote and it took couple of seconds to run :)

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm with arrays (even I hate arrays in VBA, they are not nice in data manipulation). Next time I come over to codereview!